# When I use css3 transitions, how could I get the exact transition property at each frames?

Tags: javascript, css

I know there is a transitionEnd event fired when the transition is over.

But when I want to do something during the transition, I found there is no such "onTransition" event handlers.

So is there any way to get the transition detail at each frame?

```
var el = document.getElementById('test');
el.style.webkitTransitionDuration = '.4s';
el.style.webkitTransitionProperty = 'left';
el.style.left = '500px';
```

I want to get the exactly left property at each transiton frames, just like this(fake code):

```
el.onTransition = function(e) {
    console.log(e.currentLeftValue);
}
```

Comment: Any code? What have you tried?

Comment: try to get the value of el.style.left at a specific interval. just a suggestion

Comment: @andho: That will return the final position that it will reach when the transition ends.

Comment: @andho: That won’t work. Shi Nan: First off, why do you need to do this? It’s probably not the right solution to your problem. Anyways, the `offsetLeft` property should do what you need without resorting to more complicated ways of getting a computed style.

Comment: @minitech: For example,at any frame of game or animation,you do lot of things, such as collision detection or anything else, though what I do is not that complexity,but sometimes you will need that information.

Comment: @ShiNan: I’m looking for your particular use-case, please :) Game animation would be a gross misuse of CSS transitions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no event for each frame, but you can use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame) to get something that should hopefully be called at a similar rate. As for the current properties of the animation, you can use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle).